# Multiple if let statements in Swift and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

I'm trying to compare my responses with other people's responses in the firebase database. My script currently has 2 if statements saying if it's my response, record my answers and then use that to compare against other responses, but it doesn't register my second if statement.

```
    let responsesReference = Database.database().reference().child("responses")
    responsesReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        guard let json = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            
        do {
            var similarities = [Similarity]()
            for answerElement in json {
                
                if self.currentUser.uid == answerElement.key,
                    let myanswer = answerElement.value as? [String: Any] {

                if self.currentUser.uid != answerElement.key, //DOES NOT REGISTER
                    let otheranswer = answerElement.value as? [String: Any] {
                    let percentage = myanswer.similarity(with: otheranswer)
                    similarities.append(
                        Similarity(name: answerElement.key, percentage: percentage, answer: otheranswer)
                    )
                }
            }
        }

            self.similarities = similarities.sorted(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
                return a.percentage > b.percentage
            })
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if the first if statement is executed? did yo check if both conditions of the first if statement are satisfied? Without some sample input that shows how to reproduce the problem, no answer is possible.

Comment: yes, first if statement was executed. I think the problem is that once the first if statement was true, the second one is no longer true so it doesn't execute? Not sure if there's a better way of writing this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code properly formatted (I copy and pasted it with no changes other than formatting it)

```
do {
    var similarities = [Similarity]()
    for answerElement in json {
        if self.currentUser.uid == answerElement.key, let myanswer = answerElement.value as? [String: Any] {
            if self.currentUser.uid != answerElement.key, let otheranswer = answerElement.value as? [String: Any] {
                let percentage = myanswer.similarity(with: otheranswer)
                similarities.append( Similarity(name: answerElement.key, percentage: percentage, answer: otheranswer) )
            }
        }
```

Take a look here

```
if self.currentUser.uid == answerElement.key
```

and note the next if is nested *inside* that one

```
if self.currentUser.uid == answerElement.key
   if self.currentUser.uid != answerElement.key
```

If those two vars are equal in the outside if, they will be equal with the inside if as well so the second check will always fail.

The generic solution is to use and else with your if

```
if self.currentUser.uid == answerElement.key {
   let myanswer = answerElement.value as? [String: Any] <- OPTIONAL!
   //do something because they are equal
} else {
   let otheranswer = answerElement.value as? [String: Any] <- OPTIONAL!
   // do something else because they are NOT equal
}
```

also note that you've got some optionals in that code and if those go to nil your app will either crash or silently fail with no indication as to why.

The logic isn't exactly clear in this code

```
let percentage = myanswer.similarity(with: otheranswer)
```

as each time through the loop

```
for answerElement in json {
}
```

there will only be one answer in an answerElement. e.g. there won't be a myAnswer and otherAnswer, there will only be theAnswer. Perhaps there should be a comparison to the prior answer from the loop; I'll expand on that

Here's an example based on reading in all users, getting the answer for this user, removing the user from the results and then comparing that to other users answers. Assume users uid's are used at the key to each user node (which also contains an answer they provides) and we know the auth'd users uid.

```
let thisUsersUid = "uid_1"
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users") //self.ref points to MY firebase
usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    var allUsersSnap = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    guard let index = allUsersSnap.firstIndex { $0.key == thisUsersUid } else {
        print("no user: \(thisUsersUid) found")
        return
    }
    let thisUserSnap = allUsersSnap[index] //keep this so it can be compared later
    allUsersSnap.remove(at: index)
    let thisUsersAnswer = thisUserSnap.childSnapshot("answer").value as? String ?? "No Answer"

    for otherUserSnap in allUsersSnap {
        let otherUsersAnswer = otherUserSnap.childSnapshot("answer").value as? String ?? "No Answer"
        if orherUsersAnswer == thisUsersAnswer {
            //do something because the answers match
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Problem is that I need to run both of these statements together. Essentially, I'm trying to do "if the key is my uid, pull my data; for key that are not my uid, pull data. Then compare my data with other people's data". So using two separate if statements would not enable me to combine the two data right?

Comment: @ml2008 I understand. The problem there is in your initial code, whether it's this user or another user, you're 'pulling' the same data `answerElement.value as? [String: Any]`. What and where is this users data vs another users data?

Comment: It's in the same table which is why I'm trying to combine my fetches. If you see in my firebase table, my uid is GqT6...and another person's uid is HfL3... so I want to compare my answers of yes, yes, yes with their answers yes, yes, yes

Comment: @ml2008 Go it. If you look at my answer, you'll see that, as you're iterating over the answerElements, if it's this user then do something what that `answerElement.value` data, and if its a different user do something with that `answerElement.value` data. If you want to compare other users answers to this users answers, I would get this users data from the array to keep track of it and then remove that from the array, *then* iterate over the array making the comparison.

Comment: Super helpful! Do you mind sharing a snippet of how to "keep track of it" after you remove it from the array?

Comment: @ml2008 I updated the answer - it should provide you some direction and help clean up your code.